# Add warnings to project error list from the output of a post build tool

Tags: visual-studio-2010, compiler-warnings, post-build-event, post-build

I have a command-line tool that I run as a post-build event. The tool does some analysis on the code in my project and generates a text file as its output.

I'd like to take the text file generated by the tool and add its contents to my project's Error List window as a set of warnings.

Is this possible or do I need to write my own VS extension to make it happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for a tool which will read a text file from disk and translate it into items in the Errors and Warnings dialog.  If so no unfortunately that tool does not currently exist.

However it shouldn't be that difficult to add.  There are several samples out there for adding items to the Errors window would could be applied to this scenario

- http://www.mztools.com/articles/2008/MZ2008022.aspx

Comment: Thanks Jared, this is pretty much exactly what I want to do. That link looks like a good place to start.